# Adding copyright profile to Angular CLI project in intellij IDE

Tags: javascript, angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli, copyright-display

I have added a copyright profile many times to my projects that is used IntelliJ IDE. My problem is, I can't use the same procedure to add a copyright profile to Angular-cli project. 
Is there anyone who can help me to resolve this?. And I highly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by copyright profile?

Comment: The copyright notice which is placed in each file of the project. Something like this  <!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2018. XXXXXX
  ~ All Rights Reserved
  ~ Unauthorized copying of this file...............
  ~
  -->

Comment: how does it relate with angular cli?

Comment: have you added a copyright profile to your project using IntelliJ? I need to add this copyright notice to each and every file generated by Angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for generating custom templates, files while generating files using angular-cli. Unfortunatley it is not supported with [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3549).

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I'll give up that idea.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I got this article and couldn't try and test it. so seems its possible. https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-your-own-application-template-for-angular-cli-95e22319cc24

Comment: welcome. If you could test it, let us know. I will also try, I'm bit busy these days.